# I m working in ASP.NET Core MVC, when I clicked on Id than partial view page is load but not stabled on screen

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Here are my controller's main action method and partial action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AllEngineeringCalcees()
{
      ViewBag.EnggCalcNames = GetEnggCalcName();
      return View();
}
```

The partial view action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ABCDemoPartial(int Id)
{
     if(Id == 5)
     {
         return PartialView("_AcceleratorCalc");
     }
     else
     {
         return PartialView("_DemoPartialView");
     }
}
```

I put my partial page in `View` directory like: `View/mainfolder/PartialView`.

Here are my main `.cshtml` view and partial page display view page markup:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" id="jks">
            <div class="vertical-menu">
                <a href="#" class="active sticky-top text-center">All Engineering Calcees</a>
                @foreach (var NamCalc in ViewBag.EnggCalcNames)
                {
                    <a asp-route-id="@NamCalc.CnId" title="@NamCalc.CalcRemarks" onclick="ShowPartial(@NamCalc.CnId)" id="Moon">@NamCalc.CalcName</a>

                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="PartialZone">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here are my jQuery to call and load partial view:

```
<script> /* this is first Jquery written but not succeed */ 
    var ShowPartial = function (CalcId) {
        $.ajax({
            catch: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Engineering/ABCDemoPartial",
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            data: { Id: CalcId },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#PartialZone").html(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    };
</script>

<script> /* this is another way to write Jquery but not succeed */
    $("#Moon").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ShowPartial();
        });
    function ShowPartial(CalcId) {
        $.ajax({
                catch: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ABCDemoPartial", "Engineering")',
                data: { Id: CalcId},
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('Error:' + xhr.statusText);
                },
                success: function (results) {
                    $("#PartialZone").html(results);
                }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Please check the code where I mistakes in coding. Jquery code is ok and tested on "#btnId".

When I run the code, it is working fine, but little bit mistake which not stabilizing the partial page, as I am getting Id in Foreach loop that why Partial page is load but swipe out before loading as loop finished. so I how can get id from foreach loop onclick Method that can solve the page swipes problem.

Comment: In your loop, you have `id="Moon"` for every anchor element inside the loop.Instead of an ID, you can use a class. In your AJAX request, the content-type `'application/html; charset=utf-16'` seems to be inappropriate.You should use `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`.You're declaring `ShowPartial` function twice. div tag is not properly close. `</div>` instead of `<div/>`.In your jQuery code, you are missing the parameter `CalcId` when calling the `ShowPartial` function.pass like this `ShowPartial(@NamCalc.CnId)`.The `catch` property is not standard for jQuery AJAX.

Comment: if it still does not work i recommend you to check the console to get more detail about the error

Comment: I think you see the partial view for a millisecond and then it vanish. This this is due to jQuery error which you are getting. See the console and post the error.

Comment: Jalpa Panchal sir,

Comment: Sir please share  rewrite correct from any one or also share how to get <a asp-route-id/> value to get in jquery syntax, and how can get correct get id value assigned from ShowPartial(@NamCalc.CnId)

Comment: here is the code you could try to get the id stored in data-id attribute:  `$('.calc-link').on('click', function () {
            var CalcId = $(this).data('id');` html code: `@foreach (var NamCalc in ViewBag.EnggCalcNames)
{
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="calc-link" data-id="@NamCalc.CnId" title="@NamCalc.CalcRemarks">@NamCalc.CalcName</a>
}`